# haml is not converting html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

i am using rails 2, and just installed haml. i can use it from the command line just fine, and I added config.gem "haml" to environment.rb.

but when I open the corresponding web page to the view I see "!!! Strict == == == %html{ :xmlns => "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" } %head " as text on the page.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are your views in the format action.format.builder ? E.G. foo.html.erb or bar.js.haml. if you have a haml view with an erb extension this can cause all sorts of problems.

Comment: yes they are all written as name.html.haml but i am stilling seeing things like "%h1 hi" on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

turns out after putting the gem in the environments config file, you need to restart script/server...

Comment: Thanks for remembering to share your solution so that it may help others.